# Sharing data between Android App and database based windows server

Tags: android, asp.net, database, windows

i am trying to share data between Android Application and database based on windows IIS 8.0 server. Our website is build using asp.NET.

I just want to find out what are possible ways available and their algorithm in easy language and What are the apis available in android and java library which i can use.

My application will download high amount of data including texts and images.
And want to keep my app as much lighter as possible.

Like 1 - create connection using 
2 - create session using 
3 - and so on ...

I appreciate your help.

Thanks
Karan Nagpal

Comment: you can share data by http request and sockets...it depends what kind of communication you want..

Comment: Hi deepsan, i am trying to fetch some data from data base saved on windows server, IIS 8.0 . Can you specify little more, what are different kind of communications are available.

Comment: by http request you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some easy steps which can help you.

```
1. Create a listener in asp.net which will be hosted on IIS.
2. Call listener from mobile device via HTTP.
3. Call stored procedure or simple sql statements to fetch data from database and send back to mobile device in the form of Http Response(text,xml,json).
```

Comment: hi deepson, thanks and i'll try your method and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Hello check this page you can get what you want
[Android connectivity with php and mysql](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/-)

The concept is same for every language you can use MSSql and .net in the place of php and mysql.

Thanks

Comment: hi , i got the idea of doing with php - mysql and i'll try with my server. Thanks